# Where are Adobe Lightroom (not Classic) edits stored?

Tags: lightroom, windows, lightroom-catalog, lightroom-6

I want to ensure my Lightroom edits are backed up. From what I understand, in Lightroom "Classic," a "catalog" was used to store edits. This notion seems to have been deprecated at least in Adobe Lightroom 6 if not earlier.

Where are edits stored in Lightroom 6?

**SPECIAL CLARIFICATION:** This question is about *Adobe Lightroom*, not the legacy *Photoshop Lightroom Classic*. I have no idea why Adobe is maintaining [two similar product lines](https://www.adobe.com/products/photoshop-lightroom-classic/lightroom-cc-vs-lightroom-classic.html) with confusingly similar names.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: to answer the why two products question, Lightroom CC is cloud based, streamlined for ease of use and charges $9.99 per TB per month for storage. Basically geared toward hobbyists and mobile users. Lightroom Classic is more robust and local, so geared for those who desire more control or whose catalogs have much larger data footprint. (my collective lightroom catalogs, including digitized film, contain just over 30Tb of imagery going back 40 years... that's $300 a month or I have to back up and manage it all locally anyway)

Comment: Do a search for `*.lrcat`. This will show where your LRCAT files are located in case you used a non-default directory. Warning, the Windows file search tool doesn't work well, so either perform the search from a command line window or use a third party search tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It [appears](https://www.reddit.com/r/Lightroom/comments/u12tah/do_you_guys_know_how_are_the_lightroom_files/) that edits are stored in a file called `Managed Catalog.mcat`. On my Windows 11 device, the file is stored at `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Adobe\Lightroom CC\Data\[hash key]`.

Comment: The name of the catalog can be any. The location of the catalog can be any.

Comment: @RomeoNinov do you have a source for this claim? As far as I can tell, there is exactly one catalog; it has been abstracted away, it is hidden internally, and it cannot be renamed in LR6+.

Comment: Yes, go to File menu, New Catalog and LR will give you the option to create catalog anywhere in the filesystem(s) where you have write rights. FOr example mine are on removable disk.

Comment: @RomeoNinov you seem to be referring to an older version of Lightroom. Lightroom 6+  removed the notion of catalogs. This menu option no longer exists.

Comment: https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/lightroom-classic/help/create-catalogs.html

Comment: Check this: https://imgur.com/a/nDpealJ This is LR 13, as you can see the name of my catalog is "Lightroom Catalog-v13"

Comment: @RomeoNinov you are referring "Photoshop Lightroom Classic." The question is about Adobe Lightroom. I don't blame you for being confused about Adobe's idiotic product management and naming.

Comment: @PhilipKendall you linked to "Photoshop Lightroom Classic," not Adobe Lightroom. I don't blame you for being confused about Adobe's idiotic product management and naming. https://www.adobe.com/products/photoshop-lightroom-classic/lightroom-cc-vs-lightroom-classic.html

Answer (score 1):

In Lightroom edits can be stored on two different places:

1. In specific LR database, named Catalog. Here you will find all the changes, history of edits, created duplicated, etc. on images.
2. Another place is XMP file (with the same name as original image file) where are stored changes. But you do not have the history of changes, created duplicated, etc.

In both cases to get the final image you should export.

Comment: I was asking about specific files and locations. Re #2, this does not answer my question; I was not asking about when including this option after exporting files.

Comment: @glenviewjeff, see my comment on your answer

Comment: Incidentally, XMP files are not created during exports in Lightroom 6+ unless you are using a proprietary raw format.

Comment: @glenviewjeff, XMP creation need to be configured explicitely

Comment: @romeonninov XMP files are not created during exports in Lightroom 6+. Do you have a reference for your claim?

Answer (score 1):

I am using the latest version of Lightroom classic; it has not changed. Wherever your catalogue is stored there are three files created by LR. One is .lrcat-data which are the AI masks. The other is .lrcat, which is the catalogue with all of the edits. And the third is a Previews.lrdata file.

These are the files on my Mac (Windows may be a little different).

[image]

The only difference with earlier versions of LR is that the data (previews) file used to have the .lrdata extension and there was no AI mask file. But I don't actually remember when the data file extension name changed... I also don't know what the helper file stores.

Either way, the .lrcat file is/was the catalogue with the edit history file.

If you are unsure of where the catalog is stored, you can go to the catalog settings in LR and it will tell you the location; there is even a button to take you there.

[image]

Comment: This question is about Adobe Lightroom, not Photoshop Lightroom Classic. I don't blame you for being confused due to Adobe's idiotic product management and naming conventions.

Comment: I'm afraid you are the one mistake/confused.... You are convoluting lightroom creative cloud with classic...